# Datatables: From Server-side To Client-side Filtering Boolean Data

Tags: datatables

In my opinion, server-side loads, sorts and filters (strictly?) data from the server. Now, out of curiosity, is it possible to filter my Boolean column "is_active" in a table using client-side while sorting and loading of data are using server-side? I should be able to search Boolean data by typing yes or no instead of 0 or 1. If it is possible, any hints or ideas on how to do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: yes you can....

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Any ideas or hints? Thanks.

Comment: what have you done so far? please post the code and I will examine it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When going for a server-side filtering, there is an auto-cast to string of the search values, you can see it in the documentation :
https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()
https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()

Both `input` types are `string`

You need to implement the detection server-side, checking if the string false/true is present in your query and if so, return the corresponding boolean value.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Are you referring to "smart" parameter of search() function? Thank you.

Comment: No, the `input` field.
If your table is loaded completely from the DOM the boolean search works OOTB, if it's server-side, you have to handle it yourself.
You could use something like that :
https://coderwall.com/p/fpbkeg/parse-a-boolean-from-a-string-in-javascript